# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, jpa

I have been through several posts on stackoverflow regarding the same issue; but none resolve the issue. Where on one post it was mentioned,"You probablly have 2 different versions of hibernate-jpa-api on the classpath." Thus i have checked project dependencies and doesn't find the duplication. Simultaneously no jpa jar in "Tomcat lib" directory.

My project is running absolutely as per expectations on local machines and servers. But when i deploy it on amazon server, tomcat 8 & Java 8, it throws following action on run-time.

**Exception**

```
... org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ceelive/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindJoinedTableAssociation(AnnotationBinder.java:2412)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2140)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:339)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:427)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cimple</groupId>
  <artifactId>ceelive</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ceelive Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Persistence jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl Servlet -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache tiles -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
               <!-- <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
               </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- compile only, runtime container will provide this -->
        <!-- Need this for config annotation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <!-- ceeliveDAO - Custom dependency -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.cimple</groupId>
         <artifactId>ceeliveDAO</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>ceelive</finalName>

          <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <!-- <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.3</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target> 
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/spring4ajax</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>spring4ajax</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>it.session.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maventiles.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**project dependencies**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ceelive Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ceelive ---
[INFO] com.cimple:ceelive:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.14:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.14:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] \- com.cimple:ceeliveDAO:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.940 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-02T14:51:45+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: as other posts say, different/inconsistent versions of JPA-API jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile` in the dependences. There is an old version of the `javax.persistence.JoinTable` annotation there.

Probably, servers have various class loader's strategies to load jars. In one situation jars are loaded in the right order.

So you need to exclude this transitive dependency.

**Update**

To check `@JoinTable` annotation. You can do something like this before Hibernate configuration

```
Class<?> joinTable = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .loadClass(JoinTable.class.getName());

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(joinTable.getDeclaredMethods()));
```

It should to have the `javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()` method.

Comment: So shall i consider that you are asking me to remove 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile' and then check. Right?

Comment: @AhsanIqbal  Yes. You need to exclude it in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Let me do the same, and will get back to you if issue still persist.

Comment: I did the same but issue still persist.

Comment: ...
  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
   |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
   |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
...

Comment: @AhsanIqbal Do you have now `javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile` in the dependences log?

Comment: No, it is not; but org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

Comment: @AhsanIqbal Anyway, a reason of the issue, that you have an incorrect jar in the class path.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your guidance & support. However, as you have already highlighted the root-cause of the issue. But removing dependency just didn't solve the issue. However, i have created a new project, copy the same source files; but not the pom.xml, import each dependency again (i.e. hibernate-core only & no jpa dependency), and it is working well now!

Comment: @AhsanIqbal It is strange. I am very glad :)